# Find the number of compatibility relations of [n] containing k maximal irredundant set C n,k

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Let [n] denote the set of n elements {1, 2, ... , n}. A relation on the set [n] is a subset of the Cartesian product [n] × [n]. Equivalence relations are relations that satisfy self-reflexivity, symmetry, and transferability, while compatibility relations are relations that satisfy self-reflexivity and symmetry.

PS: The result of enumerating all relations by brute-force code to find n belonging to 1 to 7 is as follows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBAMU.jpg)

Want to know how to find the case n = 10 ?

(there are 35 184 372 088 832 (2^45) relations...

You can definitely solve the problem by coding :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).